# In version 6.0 marshmallow doesn't work OnInfoWindowClickListner

Tags: android, google-maps

On other version(I'm test on emulator) this code work perfectly, but in my case(YotaPhone 2, Marshmallow) he refused to work. The problem is

```
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onInfoWindowClick");

                    OneStationFragment oneStationFragment = new OneStationFragment();
                    LatLng currentPosition = marker.getPosition();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("address", marker.getTitle());
                    bundle.putDouble("latitude", currentPosition.latitude);
                    bundle.putDouble("longitude", currentPosition.longitude);

                    oneStationFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                    fragmentTransaction.hide(StationsMapFragment.this);
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("StationMap");
                    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, oneStationFragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
            });

            googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getInfoContents");

                    View v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.custom_text_for_marker, null);
                    TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title_marker_info);
                    TextView snippet = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.snippet_marker_info);
                    title.setText(marker.getTitle());
                    snippet.setText("Информация о станции");

                    return v;
                }
            });
```

He just stop working. Plus refused work my start point.

```
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(startPoint, 10));
```

In console I'm see this

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:2
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 2
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000004/n/armeabi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm refused line `googleMap.setEnabledMyLocation(true)` and all works perfectly.